# Unbiased prediction of cluster labels

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, prediction, supervised-learning, unsupervised-learning

I am interested in evaluating the predictability of cluster labels found through unsupervised clustering. Suppose I have a dataset consisting of patients, and I use an unsupervised clustering technique to group them based on their gene expression profile. My method discovers 4 clusters. Now, I want to find out if this cluster membership is predictable from the expression data. Using the full-data unsupervised cluster labels as the output variable, I train a supervised classifier in a cross-validated manner. So, I train the classifier using 80% of the data, and evaluate the other 20% for accuracy.

Is this method biased, because the output cluster labels are learned from the full data? If it is, how can I do this in an unbiased manner? If I do the clustering in a cross-validated manner, I think I'd need to manually associate the clusters between each different fold. Since I am specifically interested in the predictability of just one of the four clusters vs. the others, I'd have to find out which cluster that is in each fold-clustering of the data through some kind of manual analysis.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Something didn't seem quite right about using a supervised method to classify objects that were labeled with an unsupervised method to begin with.

A related question: Suppose I have a set of samples with cluster labels learned from some unsupervised method. I would now like to examine new data and identify which clusters they belong to. It seems I could use supervised learning to build a cluster model on the original data, and apply it to the new data to identify cluster membership. How can I evaluate these new labels? Just with some cluster concordance measure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest the whole problem seems incorrect. If you have an algorithm (clustering technique) which builds some data partitioning then it is **always** predictable by a supervised method. In fact, under knowledge of a family of clusters used - one can propose perfect classifier (with nearly 100% accuracy). You should rethink the problem statement. In particular each clustering technique can be transformed into classifier through adding some constraints on which elements **has to** be placed in the same cluster. So if you use clusterer `C`, then one can simply transform `C` into semi-supervised method which **has to** cluster elements obtained in the training set according to given labels. This way we will nearly **always create the exact same labeling** leading to 100% accuracy.

The only way to create a valid hypothesis is to assign these **labels** by some expert, as then we cannot construct classifier which is "an expert with constraints". And so the above reasoning will fail. In other words - if you want to test whether some labeling is predictable in a supervised manner you need to obtain these labels in a way which is **hard to model** (such as human experts, nature, physics, experiments, expensive numerical evaluation) and not something such simple as a cluster model, because the whole point of supervised learning is to find this underlying model. If this model is known beforehand (not to the algorithm itself, but to us) than the whole reasoning is incorrect. You will only answer the following question:

> Is the family of models analyzed by selected clustering technique similar to the family of used classifier's hypothesis space.

Or more formally

> Is used classifier consistant with the distribution induced by the selected clustering algorithm ran on a considered dataset.